# Discord.js - Get Last Post in a Channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm very new to using Discord.JS, so this didn't come naturally to me. Sorry if it feels like I'm just being stupid, but I have no idea how I am meant to get the last post in a channel using a Discord bot.

Any helps is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi there! Have you tried anything or searched though the documentation/tutorials?

Comment: I just realized there was a class for it after I saw the answer the other user person posted ‍♂️

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`TextChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=lastMessage)s have a `lastMessage` property which lets you get the last last message sent in a channel. So, if you have a channel stored in the `channel` variable, you can get the last message sent via `channel.lastMessage`.